# Styling dropdown menu wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have set up a wordpress dropdown menu to work in the theme I have created. It is working in so far as the second level child appears when you hover over the desired parent link in the menu, but the color of the text in the dropdown item is black when you hover over the active page link which is it's parent. This only happens when the parent is active - otherwise it's ok.

The problem is on the [following page](http://new.freedomenergy.co.nz/hydro/).
How do I get it so that the dropdown text is white when the parent is active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can achive your desired result through mentioned below css add the css into your code :-

**CSS**

```
#menu ul li ul.sub-menu li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

see the attached file i guess u r looking like this...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.sub-menu > li > a,
 .menu-freedom-menu >a {color:#fff;}
```